# Requiring controller from ng-controller parent - Controller required by directive can't be found

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS fragment:

```
<div ng-controller="FooController as fooCtrl">
     <bar-directive></bar-directive>
</div>
```

And the directive for `bar-directive` looks something like:

```
angular.module("Foo").directive('barDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^FooController'],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            console.log(controllers);
        }
    };
});
```

I then get an error saying "Controller 'FooController', required by directive 'barDirective', can't be found". Can controllers not be inherited this way? Do I need to create a wrapper directive of my own?

Comment: In your `ng-controller` you're saying `FooController as fooCtrl`. So in your directive you should require `fooCtrl` not `FooController`.

Comment: I get the same error, and even if that were the case that's not very reusability friendly - is there a reason it doesn't check for a controller of the right "type" attached to parent elements, as opposed to by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require is used to require  another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function, you need to require ngController directive

```
require: ['^ngController'],
```